# Make PWM signal with arduino

Tags: arduino, integer, pwm

First sorry for my bad English and I hope u understand what I mean

I want make a PWM signal with 50% duty cycle and (f) frequency (f is an integer)

for example make 50hz signal when f=50
and 2000hz signal when f=2000

how can I do it ????

Comment: Try [arduino.se].

Comment: Read datasheet for your part and read Atmel application notes.

Comment: @TomServo, why Atmel? :-)

Comment: Depends on the Arduino you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's all you need to do, then the `tone()` function does it. Read the language reference and get familiar with all it has for you.  Have fun!

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/